# Does delete document firestore function throws not found exception? (flutter)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to understand if delete document function in firestore(flutter) return any information about the deletion like if the item is not been found? and the deletion hasn't come through?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no precondition that requires the file to exist before it can be deleted. If the file didn't exist in the first place, or was deleted already, Firestore considers the operation successful.

If you want to handle the case where the file doesn't exist different in your application, you should [use a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) to delete the file and check for its existence inside the transaction handler.